# php script causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, networking, internal-server-error

I am test a simple php script and got some problem.
My php is as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

<html><head><title>PHP Test</title></head>
<body>
<?php print( "Hello World<br />"); ?>
</body></html>
```

In the same folder, I have a htaccess file as

```
AddHandler cgi-script .php
```

Also, I run these command to ensure the permission is correct.

```
chmod 711 hello.php
chmod 644 htaccess
```

However, I got a "500 Internal Server Error" as result when I tried to reach the page. I am totally new to php. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: its the `.htaccess` file that causing the problem...

Comment: I don't think it's related to the error, but you shouldn't have `#!/usr/local/bin/php` at the beginning of a web page. That should only be used in scripts that are run from the CLI. Regarding the actual problem, check your PHP error logfile.

Comment: I have tried that but not working.

Comment: I changed the name of the "htaccess" file to be ".htaccess". Also changed that in corresponding command.

Comment: How can I check the error logfile? @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

PHP files are not run in the same way as CGI scripts. CGI scripts are executables and need to be able to run from the commandline by themselves. PHP files need to be run through an interpreter, and typically can't use the `#!` pragma at the top of their files to invoke an interpreter like Perl or Ruby or Python (etc) scripts can.

I've usually seen the following:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

which tells Apache to run the PHP file through the PHP interpreter.

Comment: First, is that supposed to be .htaccess  not htaccess  ?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be .htaccess, not htaccess.

Comment: I tried what you said and now it becomes "forbidden". @Ava Jarvis

Comment: Progress! I should have noted that your chmod to 711 should probably be 755.

Comment: Now the result just shows the code itself but I expect to see only helloworld. Just for your information, I am refering this website https://www.cise.ufl.edu/help/web/php @Ava Jarvis

Comment: Interesting. From what you tell me, it sounds like either there is no PHP module in your Apache, or that support is not at version 5 of PHP. - I just saw your edit. That is interesting. It sounds like they're using PHP as an interpreter and not as an Apache module. I'm not sure what else can be tried at this point.